# why javascript or jquery codes doesn't work in Area layout page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add jquery accordion menu in my "AdminLayout.cshtml".
When I use all code in root, menu works truly, but when I add them to "AdminLayout.cshtml" in Admin Area, it's JavaScript code doesn't work! 
My roating is true.
Why?

jquery code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function ($) {  
       $('#accordion-3').dcAccordion({
           eventType: 'click',
           autoClose: false,
           saveState: false,
           disableLink: false,
           showCount: false,
           speed: 'slow'
       });
  </script>
```

Html code:

```
    <ul class="accordion" id="accordion-3">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>  <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a><ul>
            <li><a href="#">Mobile Phones &#038; Accessories</a><ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Part A</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Part B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Part C</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Part D</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Accessories</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 14</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 15</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul></li>
    </ul>
```

and use these file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post your view in the area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added this line to my code and worked fine...

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/Admin/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")"
     type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Thanks all...

Answer (score 0):

I think its because there is a fumble in script reference URL. So to overcome this situation use **[Url.Content()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)** method. It converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path.

**Example :**

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js")'  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.min.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC3 you should use:

```
@Url.Content("~/path/to/file/from/root")
```

In the `src` attribute of your script tags